# Unable to fix the spring-tx.xsd file issue in my Spring MVC XML project

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to migrate from a Spring 3 (Java 1.8.X) to a Spring 6 (openJDK 19) application. When I try to run the ap on the server I receive this warning:
`ResourceEntityResolver - DTD/XSD XML entity [https://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd] not found, falling back to remote https resolution`
This did never happened before while we were developing the Spring 3 version. I read several posts about this and all pointed that I had to check if the package `spring-tx` was indeed in the project and loading the schemas file.

This is my spring config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="..."
    xmlns:xsi="..."
    xmlns:p="..."
    xmlns:aop="..."
    xmlns:tx="http://www.spring framework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="..."
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.spring framework.org/schema/tx https://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
        <bean id="sessionFactory">...</bean>
    
        <bean name="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource"/>...</bean>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar.services" />
</bean>
```

I tried checking and changing version of the spring-tx.xsd file of the project. I still have no clue what should I try.

I had to omit most of the lines referring to xml locations because it was marking he question as spam.

Comment: looks like you muss the dependency for `spring-tx`. BTW: Stop using the XML based configuration. Move over to the java based configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that even though the dependency was loaded in the project, it wasn't being deployed in Eclipse's Tomcat server. I had to:

1. remove the project from the server
2. clean the tomcat workspace
3. then publish it again